# Finding number of Possible Combinations

Tags: permutations, combinations

I need to find the number of possible combinations for a combinatorial poem with word banks.

Each Poem will have 12 lines. The ordering of the lines is randomized, 12!

However, within each line there are 11 possible words to be selected. Only one word is selected in each iteration in each line. Each line has a completely different word bank, so on the first line the third word can be chosen from a specific word bank while the second line can choose the 11th word from a different specific word bank.

wordBank1-11 words -only word selected 
wordBank2-11 words -only word selected
wordBank3-11 words -only word selected
.....
wordBank12-11 words -only word selected

How many possible combinations are there altogether?

Comment: How many words are in each word bank?  Can you compute the number of possible first lines (before the lines are reordered)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  This is very confusing.  How many words are there in the word banks?  What do you mean by an iteration?  What does it mean to say "each line has a completely different word bank?"  Are all words on a line chosen from the same word bank?